# Mean and variance of number of steps to reach one node from another in random walk on weighted, undirected graph

Tags: graph-theory, random-walk

Suppose I have a connected, undirected graph with edge weights, and I do a random walk over it such that the probability of moving from any node *u* to one of its neighbors *v* is equal to the weight of edge *(u,v)* divided by the sum of the weights of the edges incident to *u*. Is there a closed form for the mean and variance of the number of steps it takes to reach any node *j* from any other node *i* on such a walk, with *i* and *j* not necessarily neighbors?